# How to read from buffer and store as int and float variables

Tags: java

I have an input stream in the given format which is coded in arduino programming software. I used Netbeans+JDK to read from the serial port.

Left Leg

Time(ms): 14448
Accelerometer: -1.38,2.2,1.3
Gyroscope: 1.0,-0.9,1.2
Magnetometer: -2,1,-1.2

I need to write an algorithm to count the number of steps, so I need to extract only the accelerometer (x,y,z) readings from the above input stream. Below given is the code.

```
while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
    //int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
    char buffer = (char)inputStream.read();
    this.bufferRx += buffer;
    System.out.print(buffer);
}
```

What can I do to get the time and accelerometer x,y,z values only from the string buffer and store it as int and float values?

Comment: what is the entire inputstream string will be like?

Comment: Time(ms): 14
Gyroscope    : -1.86, -0.46, -3.01
Accelerometer: -0.48, -0.83, 0.21
Magnetometer : 0.27, 0.02, -0.27

Time(ms): 2627
Gyroscope    : -1.65, -1.56, -3.20
Accelerometer: -0.48, -0.83, 0.21
Magnetometer : 0.27, 0.02, -0.27



Time(ms): 7852
Gyroscope    : -1.27, 0.80, -3.66
Accelerometer: -0.48, -0.83, 0.20
Magnetometer : 0.27, 0.02, -0.27

Time(ms): 10465
Gyroscope    : -1.56, -1.68, -2.79
Accelerometer: -0.48, -0.83, 0.20
Magnetometer : 0.27, 0.02, -0.27

This is the input stream..

Comment: What I know is to use "IndexOf " in java to point to the string. But Im not sure how to write a code with it.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain old java:

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "ascii"));

    for (String line; null != (line = br.readLine()); )
    {
        if (line.startsWith("Accelerometer:"))
        {
            String[] split = line.split("[:,]");
            float x = Float.parseFloat(split[1]);
            float y = Float.parseFloat(split[2]);
            float z = Float.parseFloat(split[3]);
            // do somehting with the data.
            System.out.printf("%f,%f,%f\r\n",x,y,z);
        }
    }
```

having fun with java 8:

```
    Iterator<float[]> iterator = 
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "ascii"))
            .lines()
            .filter(s -> s.startsWith("Accelerometer:"))
            .map(s -> s.split("[:,]"))
            .map(p -> new float[]{
                    Float.parseFloat(p[1]),
                    Float.parseFloat(p[2]),
                    Float.parseFloat(p[3]),
            }).iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
        float[] p = iterator.next();
        System.out.printf("%f,%f,%f\r\n", p[0], p[1], p[2]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to split your data (given that that is the string it is passing) using RegEx or simply String#split, then cast the individual String parts to their respective values (Integer.parseInt etc)

However I personally would modify your Arduino code to output more machine readable data (XML, JSON, ...) because that is frankly not the way machines communicate.